# Migrating users and pwd from AD to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, active-directory, migration

Let me describe the problem, my current portal is using AD login and pwd details to authenticate external users. I will have the new portal which will keep logins and pwds in SQL Server in a table. I need to migrate logins/pwds from AD domain to the sql database so external users can use their old password. Is it possible? How should i approach that?

Thank you for any help,
Rafal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gathering the list of usernames should not be a problem.  However SQL Server stores hashed versions of passwords, and presumably Active Directory does this differently.  I don't see any solution except to create a bridge application under Active Directory that logs them into SQL Server under a temporary password and let's them assign a new password.

Answer (score 0):

The permissions should be with the databases. Perhaps you've lost the association between the server logins and the database users. See if their SIDs are different. If so you can fix them with

ALTER USER  with login =
 
or

exec sp_change_users_login (check books online for how to use this)
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174378.aspx